# Правильно ли построено сложноподчиненное предложение с последовательным подчинением придаточных?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, редактура, сложное-предложение

> Очевидно, брат все время был рядом, рассчитывая, видимо, на то, что
>   Джаред непременно доложит о его исчезновении и останется только
>   подождать, чтобы Мидир отправился на поиски и покинул поляну.

Уважаемые знатоки великого и могучего, как вы считаете, правильно ли согласованы между собой глаголы разных времен в этом предложении? И еще: не нужна ли внезапно запятая после слова «исчезновении»? И уж попутно: с вводными словами тут не перебор?

Comment: На мой взгляд, всё правильно (включая пунктуацию). В русском возможен мысленный перенос во время дейсвия и не требуется механического согласования времён, как напр. в английском. Из "видимо" и "очевидно" лучше оставить что-то одно.

Comment: @Alex_ander Утешили и убедили.)))

Answer (score 3):

У меня вызывает вопрос сочетание "**останется только подождать, чтобы Мидир отправился на поиски..."**

Вот понятное предложение: Надо было немного подождать, чтобы взять воров с поличным. [2003.01.15]. Здесь действие уже происходит, и наблюдатели ждут удобного момента.

А в заданном предложении действие еще не началось, и его начало как бы зависит от наблюдателей.

Может быть, надо сказать так: ...и останется только подождать, пока Мидир не отправится на поиски, покинув поляну.

Comment: На мой взгляд, "подождать, пока Мидир не отправится" создаёт недопонимание, ставя ненужный вопрос: _подождать_ до этого момента **с чем** (с каким неназванным действием со стороны "ждущих" - чего не делать "пока")? В исходном же варианте (у меня нет к нему вопросов) ясно, что ждать нужно действий персонажа (а дальше видно будет, что выйдет и делать ли хоть что-то), а не временить с какими-то своими.

Comment: Как правильно? (1) Дети решили подождать, чтобы родители ушли из дома. (2) Дети решили подождать, пока родители уйдут из дома.

Comment: В данном контексте отправить родителей подальше - не самоцель: после их ухода можно будет, как обычно, заняться шалостями. Пока родители дома, рано заниматься чем хочется. Отсюда "пока". Другой контекст: ожидание свершения задуманного или желание убедиться, что задуманное получилось. _Дети вернулись с пятёрками - им оставалось только подождать, чтобы родители купили обещанные игрушки._

Answer (score 1):

1. Мне кажется, без запятой возможно прочтение, что "Джаред доложит и 
   останется", поэтому запятая не помешает.
2. Думаю, корректней употребить *дождаться* вместо *подождать*: "... **дождаться**, чтобы Мидир отправился на поиски и покинул поляну".

("Подождать, чтобы..." можно понять как "подождать, для того чтобы...")